# How to solve this javascript error, I am using ToolScriptManager for UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am trying to register below mentioned javascript for using with GridView to add freeze functioality on GridView.
When compiling an error is thrown **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined**

How it can be fixed.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // This Script is used to maintain Grid Scroll on Partial Postback
    var scrollTop;
    //Register Begin Request and End Request 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    //Get The Div Scroll Position
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) 
    {
    var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
    scrollTop=m.scrollTop;
    }
    //Set The Div Scroll Position
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
    {
    var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
    m.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(endRequest);
        var _postBackElement;</br>
        function initializeRequest(sender, e) 
     {
if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) 
{ e.set_cancel(true); }

    var m = document.getElementById('divGrid'); 
    scrollTop=m.scrollTop; 
    } 
    function endRequest(sender, e)
    { 
    var m = document.getElementById('divGrid'); 
    m.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    } 
            </script>



try adding the following in web.config under <system.web>
<httpHandlers>
<remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: Exception is being thrown on very first line i.e. Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

Comment: No this didn't worked for me. I am using ToolScriptManager instead of ScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite an old post, but thought it was important to identify there is one more thing identified in my code to identify.  simply put, I didn't place the javascript code in the correct location specifically when using a master page.

This works for me using a toolkitscriptmanager in the master page with EnablePartialRendering="true"

[Reference:](http://ajax.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ViewSample.aspx?sref=Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.beginRequest/cs/default.aspx)

The code is not complete, but should provide enough detail.

```
<asp:content id="Content2" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var scrolltop;
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            var elem = $get("scrollableContainer");

            scrolltop = elem.scrollTop;
        }

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            var elem = $get("scrollableContainer");

            elem.scrollTop = scrolltop;
        }
    </script>

    <asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
        <contenttemplate>
        </contenttemplate>
    </asp:updatepanel>
```

Hope this helps!